# probability game, can't find prove

Tags: probability

Lets assume i have a game, where I get to pick a random number between 1 and 10, while my friend needs to pick a number between 1 and 20. The one who picks smaller number, wins.

So I know I have 75% chances to win this game. I just know that... if we would play 100 times, I would win about 75% of the time. The problem is, I don't know how to prove that.

I have number of events and occurrences, but I just don't understand where 75% comes from. I would appreciate it.

Comment: You should edit this question to indicate whether you and your friend are picking integers or real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N_1 \le 10$ and $N_2 \le 20$.

$$P(N_1 \le N_2) =\\
= P(N_1 \le N_2| N_2 \le 10) \, P(N_2 \le 10) + P(N_1 \le N_2| N_2 > 10) \, P(N_2 > 10) =\\ 
=\dfrac{1}{2} \, \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2} = 0.75,$$

where $$P(N_1 \le N_2| N_2 \le 10)= \dfrac{1}{2}$$ by symmetry.

**Edit:** As noticed in the comments by @dhrab if you assume a uniform distribution over $[1,20]$, $[1,10]$ does not have the half of the probability. So the result is false. What do you refer to when you say "pick at random"? For instance it is still $0.75$ if you interpret the statement as suggested by @saulspatz or if you start from $0$ and not from $1$.

Comment: @saulspatz, yes I assume that the probability of picking the same number is $0$, since I interpreted picking a random number as from a uniform continuous distribution

Comment: Then it should be uniformly continuous on $[1,20]$ so that $P(N_2\leq10)=9/19$

Comment: @dhrab you are right, I was too sloppy!

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the event "Your friend picks a number larger than $10$", and $B$ the event "Your friend picks a smaller number than you". Then the law of total probability says
$$
P(B)=P(A)P(B\mid A)+P(\overline A)P(B\mid\overline A)
$$
Intuitively, the $25\%$ probability for your friend to win comes from the fact that half the time, he wins half the time.

Answer (score 1):

With probability $.5$ your friend picks a number  greater than $10,$ and you win automatically.

With probability $.5$ you both pick a number from $1$ to $10.$  In this case, with probability $.1$ you both pick the same number,  with probability $.45$ you pick the smaller number, and  with probability $.45$ your friend picks the smaller number.

Your probability of winning depends on what happens when you both pick the same number.

I guess Arthur and Gio assume that you and your friend are picking real numbers, not integers, but I doubt that's what you meant.  When somebody tells me, "Pick a number between 1 and 10," they're always disconcerted when I pick $\pi.$

Comment: ;)I agree the question is not precise, but otherwise the result is not $0.75$

Comment: @Gio Well, you could assume that they're picking integers, and in the case of a tie, they go again.  In fact, that's how I interpreted it, but I admit that I was reading quite a bit between the lines.  I didn't want to go into that in my answer before the OP clarified the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I preassume that you pick randomly a number in $\{1,\dots,10\}$ and your friend picks randomly a number in $\{1,\dots,20\}$.

If $X$ denotes the number chosen by you and $Y$ is the number chosen by your friend.

$$\begin{aligned}P\left(X<Y\right) & =P\left(Y>10\right)+P\left(X<Y\wedge Y\leq10\right)\\
 & =P\left(Y>10\right)+P\left(X<Y\mid Y\leq10\right)P\left(Y\leq10\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{2}+P\left(X<Y\mid Y\leq10\right)\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Further we have:

- $P\left(X<Y\mid Y\leq10\right)=P\left(Y<X\mid Y\leq10\right)$
- $P\left(X<Y\mid Y\leq10\right)+P\left(X=Y\mid Y\leq10\right)+P\left(Y<X\mid Y\leq10\right)=1$

so that $P\left(X<Y\mid Y\leq10\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}P\left(X=Y\mid Y\leq10\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{10}$

So we end up with:

$P\left(X<Y\right)=\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{10}\right)\frac{1}{2}=\frac{29}{40}$